# how to display values from database to wordpress page using select where conditon query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Iam trying to edit table details.my edit link is `<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/edit?id=<?php echo $user->id;?>">EDIT</a>`
and im create a new page.(edit.php)to view edit details. id display($id=$_GET['id']; echo $id; in this page but that id's corresponding vales are not display.

mysql query is : `$mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->test WHERE id = '$id'", ARRAY_A );`

if iam trying to echo $mylink->test_name; ("test_name" is my table field name)
nothing to display(empty)
`

Comment: <?php foreach ($mylink as $user)
       {
           $name= $user->test_name;
           $offer= $user->test_offer;
           $prize=$user->test_prize;
           $id=$user->id;
     ?> 
<td><?php echo $name;?></td> 
                       <td><?php echo $offer;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $prize;?></td>

Comment: Have a read about parametrised queries

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for the same**

```
 $mylinks = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '$id'" );

 foreach( $mylinks as $mylink ) {
    echo $mylink->test_name;
 }
```